# Nordic nrf51822 - Why doesn't it read all data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy

[image: Nordic_HRM]

I'm wondering why the Nordic toolbox app doesn't detect all the data (After about 50 seconds it samples only selective data)

Any body knows why?

Specifications:

1. conn interval min : 20ms
2. conn interval max : 40ms
3. slave latency : 0
4. supervision timeout : 4000ms

***Is it due to the connection interval is getting changed?(If so how can I monitor the connection interval - I know that we can't set it via app)
i.e. Does connection interval in iOS BLE change by any chance?***